# C# making a array that's sorted

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to make a array that wouldn't allow 3 same numbers be near each other. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

**Output I want :**

```
Input         1 4 2 4 4 4 5 3 9 5 6 

Output
First Pass :  1 4 2 4 4 5 4 3 9 5 6 
Second Pass : 1 4 2 4 5 4 4 3 9 5 6 
Third Pass :  1 4 2 4 5 4 3 4 9 5 6
```

**Code:**

```
int[,] numbers = new int[10, 10];
            Random randoms = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    int skaitlis;
                    do
                    {
                        skaitlis = randoms.Next(1, 6);
                    }
                    while (!DrikstPievienotx(skaitlis, i, j, numbers) && !DrikstPievienoty(skaitlis, i, j, numbers));
                    numbers[i, j] = skaitlis;
                    Console.Write(numbers[i, j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        static bool DrikstPievienotx(int sk, int x, int y, int[,] arr)
        {
            if (x > 1)
            {
                if (arr[x - 1, y] == sk && arr[x - 2, y] == sk)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        static bool DrikstPievienoty(int sk, int x, int y, int[,] arr)
        {
            if (y > 1)
            {
                if (arr[x, y - 1] == sk && arr[x, y - 2] == sk)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Please don't correct the code, just give me hints, i'd like to fix it myself.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong, the output is wrong, you have an exception, it doesn't compile?

Comment: The output is wrong. When I had only the "DrikstPievienotx" function it sorted everything correctly (the x values). When I added "DrikstPievienoty" everything messed up. I can't figure why.

Comment: You don't want to sort the numbers... then make your algorithm, where you compare each number to all other number and when you get two same numbers in adjacent positions go and compare with next position and if they are different, swap them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while condition is false, try to understand what it really does...

Now you are looking for a new number each time this condition is true :

```
!DrikstPievienotx(skaitlis, i, j, numbers) && !DrikstPievienoty(skaitlis, i, j, numbers)
```

so if you have 3 same number on x axis **AND** if you have 3 same number on y axis you try again.
if you want to avoid both you should do more :

```
!DrikstPievienotx(skaitlis, i, j, numbers) || !DrikstPievienoty(skaitlis, i, j, numbers)
```

Witch is try again if you have 3 same number on x axis **OR** if you have 3 same number on y axis.

Comment: I guess I just fixed it. No idea why everything works now. I guess i'll just leave it like that. :/ Thank you, Thomas!

Comment: So what did you put on your condition? did you understood your error?

Comment: Sorry, comment messed up. In while condition i deleted the "!" on DrikstPievienoty. No idea why it works.

Comment: I gave you the answer, if you want to do programming, you should really take the time to undestand what you are doing rather than trying to guess.
Good luck for your project!

Comment: Oh. Thank you Thomas. I just didn't think about that. I'm pretty new at programming, I make stupid mistakes like this all the time.

Comment: This is why stack overflow exist, to help each other!